# localStorage causes infinite refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing localStorage for a simple form. When user open up the form, all the saved data will be displayed in the corresponding input filed, and after user fills out the form, all the info will be saved.

Now I can save the data and also display the data, just that when I reopen the page, data is displayed while the page's being infinite refreshed. Does anybody know how did that happen?

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<form id="formData">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Please fill in</legend>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input name="name" type="text"><br/>
    <label for="txt">Introduction:</label>
    <input name="txt" type="textarea"><br/>
    <label for="someCheck">Checkbox:</label>    
    <input name="someCheck" type="checkbox"><br/>
    <label for="someRadio">Radio:</label>   
    <input name="someRadio" type="radio"><br/>          
    <input type="submit">
</fieldset>
```

CSS:

```
fieldset{
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
label{
    width: 18%;
    display: inline-block;
}
input{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
input[type=submit]{
    padding: 2px 10px;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 6px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Jquery:

```
if(Modernizr.localstorage){
    var form=document.querySelector('#formData');
    if(localStorage.formData){
        //step one: 
        //display the stored value, title=my+title&...&
        var fd;
        fd=localStorage.formData.split('&'); //['title=my+title']
        $.each(fd,function(index,pair){
            pair=pair.split('=');//title,my+title
            console.log(pair[0]+":"+pair[1]);
            if(pair[1]==="on"){
                form[pair[0]].checked=true;
            }else{
                form[pair[0]].value=unescape(pair[1]).replace(/\+/g," ");               
            }
        });
    }
    //step two:
    //save form to storage when filled outline
    form.submit(function(e){
        //serialize form data to url
        localStorage.formData=$(this).serialize();
        alert('Okay, refresh the page now.');
        e.preventDefault();
    });

}
```

Comment: does your form have a closing `</form>` tag?

Comment: this is not how you use localstorage. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: @Occam'sRazor FYI `localStorage.foo = "bar"` is a shorthand for `localStorage.setItem("foo", "bar")`. Etc etc. Objects.

Comment: Apart from the weird usage of `localStorage`, `form.submit` doesn't take any arguments, hence the form is submitted, and the page is reloaded as the server response. See [submit()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) at MDN.

Comment: @Occam'sRazor Addition to what Roko has replied, the browser will automatically render the missing close form tag even if I didn't add it.

Comment: @JaniceZhong that's true but If the browser has to guess  guess to put it it could have unintended consequenses...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The infinite reload is caused by `form.submit()`. That is triggering the HTML submit action. Part of which is to reload the page.

I suspect what you really want is to listen for the submit event and do the local storage save:

```
document.querySelector("#formData").addEventListener("submit", function(e){
    localStorage.formData=$(this).serialize();
    alert('Okay, refresh the page now.');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I changed form to $(form) then the problem is fixed... Maybe you are right anyways

Comment: Yes that would fix it because now you're using [jquery's submit method](https://api.jquery.com/submit/). Which, somewhat confusingly, acts like an event listener if given arguments, but if given no arguments acts like the `submit()`.